# If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables and $X$ and $X-Y$ are also independent then $X$ is a constant almost surely.

Tags: probability, independence

I have been thinking about this problem but I haven't found an answer.

> **Problem.** I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are independent  ($X \perp Y $)  in $( \Omega, \mathcal{F}, P  )$. In addition to that, $X$ and $X-Y$ are also independent ($X \perp X-Y $) .
>
> I have to prove that $X$ is a constant almost surely ($\exists c \in \mathbb{R} : P(X=c) = 1$). That is, $X$ is a degenerate random variable.

I suppose I should take the supremum of a set. Maybe I should try to discover that $P(X\leq0)=1$ or $P(X\leq0)=1$.
Would you mind giving me some ideas or hints?

Comment: Use independence to evaluate $E[X(X-Y)]$ in two different ways. What does the result imply about the variance of $X$? Edit: As noted by @geetha290krm, this assumes finite expectation and is therefore wrong.

Comment: @averagemonkey You cannot assume that they have finite expectation.

Comment: Indeed, I shouldn't assume finite expectation. I don't even know something special about the probability measure $P$. I know that if $B_{1},B_{2} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ then $P(X \in B_{1}, X-Y \in B_{2}) = P(X \in B_{1})P(X-Y \ in B_{2}) $ and $P(X \in B_{1}, Y \in B_{2}) = P(X \in B_{1})P(Y \in B_{2}) $.

Comment: The easiest proof is using characterisitc functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use characteristic functions to avoid use of moments.

Hints: We have $Ee^{itY}=Ee^{it[X-(X-Y)]}=Ee^{itX} Ee^{-it(X-Y)}=Ee^{itX}Ee^{-itX}Ee^{itY}$. Since $Ee^{itY}\neq 0$ for $|t|$ sufficiently small, this gives $|Ee^{itX}|^{2}=1$   for $|t|$ sufficiently small. This implies that $X$ is almost surely constant.  Ref. Corollary on p. 75 of A Course in Probability Theory by K L Chung.

Answer (score 3):

For any bounded continuous $\varphi(\cdot)$, define $\widetilde{\varphi}(x) = \mathbf{E}[\varphi(x - Y)]$. Also, let $B$ be any Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then by the independence of $X-Y$ and $Y$,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[\varphi(X-Y) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X \in B\}}]
&= \mathbf{E}[\varphi(X-Y)] \cdot \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X \in B\}}] \\
&= \mathbf{E}[\mathbf{E}[\varphi(X-Y) ] \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X \in B\}}]
\end{align*}

On the other hand, by conditioning on $X$ and utilizing the independence of $X$ and $Y$,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[\varphi(X-Y) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X \in B\}}]
&= \mathbf{E}[ \mathbf{E}[ \varphi(X-Y) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X \in B\}} \mid X]] \\
&= \mathbf{E}[\widetilde{\varphi}(X) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{X \in B\}} ].
\end{align*}

Since this is true for any $B$, by comparing both sides, we get

$$ \mathbf{E}[\varphi(X-Y) ] = \widetilde{\varphi}(x) = \mathbf{E}[\varphi(x - Y)] $$

for $\mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot)$-almost every $x$. Since $\varphi$ is arbitrary, this then implies that

$$X-Y \stackrel{\text{d}}= x - Y $$

for $\mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot)$-almost every $x$. However, this can only make sense when $X$ is degenerate, for otherwise we would have been able to find $x \neq x'$ such that $x - Y$ and $x' - Y$ have the same distribution. Therefore the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

$\text{cov}(X,X-Y) = \text{var}(X) - \text{cov}(X,Y)$

If $X,Y$ are independent $\text{cov}(X,Y) = 0$

Which implies $\text{var}(X) =0$

Comment: You cannot assume finiteness of moments.

Comment: This would be a great solution if we knew the existence of second moments -- but @geetha290krm is correct that we cannot assume it. Maybe this can be fixed with a truncation argument somehow? I haven't thought much about it. (My first reaction is that such an argument would risk destroying independence, though.)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I doubt if there is a truncation argument. Independence of $X$ and $X-Y$ would be lost when you truncate $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: So we have this result when $Var(X), Var(Y) < \infty$.  Consider $f_{n} (\omega) = \omega $ if $\omega \leq n$ and $f_{n} (\omega) = 0 $ if $\omega \geq n$. This function is measurable. Define $ X_{n} = f_{n} \circ X $. Also $(X-Y)_{n} = f_{n} \circ (X-Y)$ . Then $(X-Y)_{n}, X_{n}, Y_{n}$ are bounded random variables. Hence $Var(X_{n})$ is defined. Also, $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n}(\omega) = X(\omega)$.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (X -Y)_{n}(\omega) = (X-Y)(\omega)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} Y_{n}(\omega) = Y(\omega)$. By using the first case we have that: $X_{n} = c$ almost surely. Hence, for those $A= \{ \omega \in \Omega: X_{n} (\omega) = c \}$ is true that   $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_{n}(\omega) = X(\omega)$. Which means that $X=c$ almost surely (at least for those $\omega \in A$ and $P(A) = 1$).